# Erro ao executar programa Java - Mapping Servlet Web.xml

Tags: java, java-ee, aplicação-web, servlet

Tenho o seguinte software, ele deve permitir que eu passe um arquivo, vai emitir uma mensagem no console para apenas para positivar o acesso a uma classe e lista o resultado na página, estou começando e não sei o motivo do seguinte erro:

[image: Console após o erro]

Os arquivos são os seguintes:

**Principal.html**
`Neste arquivo inicio o programa, ele tem um input para o arquivo e um submit`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Manipulador</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="ArqSQL.do">
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" size="chars" />
        <input type="submit" value="Envia Arquivo" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EntradaArquivo.java**
`Este é o Servlet deve listar o conteúdo do arquivo, acredito que faça isto no console`

```
package Model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class EntradaArquivo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ArquivoSQL arqsql = new ArquivoSQL();

        String endereco = req.getParameter("arquivo");
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String enderecoCompleto = context.getRealPath(endereco);
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(enderecoCompleto));
        String str;
        while((str = buff.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str); //Lista o que tem no seu arquivo
        arqsql.trataArquivo(str);
    }
    buff.close();
}
}
```

**web.xml**
`Este arquivo deve apontar para o servidor qual arquivo executar (EntradaArquivo.java) quando a função ArqSQL.do for usada`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ManipuladorSQL</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Model.EntradaArquivo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ManipuladorSQL</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ManipuladorSQL/ArqSQL.do*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Principal.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**ArquivoSQL.java**
`Este só escreve uma mensagem no console, mas para frente deverá trabalhar no conteúdo antes de devolver à página`

```
package Model;

public class ArquivoSQL {
    public void trataArquivo(String str) {
        if(str.equals("o")) {
            System.out.println("achei a linha que tem escrito SELECT nela!!");
        }
    }
}
```

É meu primeiro programa Web e não sei onde estou errando, o que quero é pegar um arquivo trabalhar no conteúdo e listar na página, mas no momento só repassar um OK já está bom, se precisarem de mais informações é só falar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez tenha uma confusão com o nome do projeto (`ManipuladorSQL`), q vira um contexto no tomcat,  e a servlet (também `ManipuladorSQL`) q vc cadastrou no `web.xml`.

De qualquer forma, mude essa entrada no web.xml de

```
<url-pattern>/ManipuladorSQL/ArqSQL.do*</url-pattern>
```

para

```
<url-pattern>/ArqSQL.do</url-pattern>
```

Acredito que assim irá funcionar. Mas fica a dica para vc não se atrapalhar: costume colocar sufixo nas classes conforme a funcionalidade dela ou de quem ela herda (ManipuladorSQLServlet, EnderecoEntity, ConsultaCEPService, etc.).

Comment: Deu certo, alterei o ```servlet name``` para **ManipuladorSQLServlet**  e usei o caminho que indicou, agora mudou o erro para ```Error 500 nullpointerexception```, ja sei qe é na linha do ```EntradaArquivo.java``` ```String enderecoCompleto = context.getRealPath(endereco);``` o ```getRealPath``` não está conseguindo traduzir o endereço virtual e  devolve ```null```, vou estudar uma forma de resolver o problema, obrigado.

Comment: Bons estudos ai @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas !

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @Fulvius está correta, incluo esta para registrar nesta pergunta que é possível mapear um `Servlet 3.0` em sua própria classe com uma anotação `@WebServlet`, como ficou no arquivo EntradaArquivo.java:

```
@WebServlet("/ArqSQL.do")
public class EntradaArquivo extends HttpServlet {
```